# Are required functions read from disk on each call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have just written a NodeJS app, where I split all functions into their own files. Now I wonder if that was a bad idea.

My concern/question is how many times these function files are read from disk? Once or each time the function is called?

I suppose the question could be simplified to how many times are `function.js` read from disk in the following case?

```
while (true) {
  const f = require('./function');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/) indicates it will be read from disk once only:

> It is worth noting that each time you subsequently require an already-required file, the `exports` object is cached and reused.

And then goes on to also demonstrate that any state contained within the exports from that is also reused across different calls to `require`, ie each call to `require` gets the exact same `exports` reference.

Comment: Would that also be the case if the required function read a config file from disk? Ie. would the config file then also only be read once?

Comment: Can't say I've tested explicitly, but that is certainly how the documentation reads - it essentially reads and runs the file once the first time you `require` it, then reuses the existing/cached `exports` on every other call.

Answer (score 0):

Only once. It will read from cache there on. Module cache to be more precise. From official Docs.